# Get NHibernate XML mapping attributes through models?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

If I have a model with a decimal property:

```
<property name="Prop" column="prop" type="decimal" 
 precision="19" scale="4" not-null="true" />
```

is it possible to get the `precision` and `scale` attributes in C# without parsing the HBM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(). Look at PropertyNames and PropertyTypes in the returnes IClassMetadata.

Comment: I don't see anything in the relevant `PropertyTypes` entry (`NHibernate.Type.DecimalType`) about *precision*, *scale*, or the example values used in the mapping of *19* and *4*.

Comment: Of the IType you located, you should use the SqlTypes() method (passing null should be fine). It will return an array of SqlType with one member for each column (which in this case will be only one). Alternatively, cast the IType to NHibernate.Type.NullableType and access the SqlType property.